# how to elimate valeur from database in registrationform

Tags: symfony

In registrationform, i need to display Admin in the interface that's why i put this code but the result is Expected Litteral got'"':

```
$builder->add(
        'type','entity', array
                 (
                'attr'=>array('class'=>"form-control",'data-type'=>'type'),
                'class'    => 'PublishDemandsBundle:Type',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'empty_value' => 'Select Type',
                'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) 
                 {
                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                  ->andWhere('u.name != "Admin" ')

                  ;
                 }
                 ));
```

Comment: this is the error exactly:[Syntax Error] line 0, col 66: Error: Expected Literal, got '"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
->where('u.name != :name')
->setParameter('name', "admin")
```